# Measure of similarity of two parametric closed curves?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

Given two closed curves given parametrically by: $(x_1(t),y_1(t))$ and $(x_2(t),y_2(t))$ with $t=0..2\pi$

I want to find a functional $f(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ which is zero when the curves are the same curve and non-zero when the curves are different. e.g. if both curves are different parametrisations of the same curve the $f$ whould be zero.

So the function should be invariant under diffeomorphisms like $t\rightarrow g(t)$.

Is there a nice symmetric functional that one can find that does this?

Comment: How about $\int_0^{2\pi}(x_1(s_1)-x_2(s_2))^2+(y_1(s_1)-y_2(s_2))^2dt$ where $s_1$, $s_2$ are the arclength parameter of each curve?

Comment: @Chrystomath This would only work if x1(0)==x2(0)  and y1(0)==y2(0). Which in general is very hard to solve. (it could be a 100th degree polynomial even). Mind you I guess if we took a continuous product of this expression with all starting points on the second curve this could work. But I hoped there would be a simpler expression.

Comment: But they're the same curve, no? Why wouldn't $x_1(0)=x_2(0)$?